# How to execute code in design mode for winforms

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, windows-forms-designer, designer

I **WANT** to execute code when I open a winform in the designer. In particular, I want the designer to automatically size the working form to a percentage of my screen. similar to this:

```
pForm.Size = New Drawing.Size(MyScreen.WorkingArea.Width * 0.75, MyScreen.WorkingArea.Height * 0.75)
```

There's got to be a way besides manually modifying the initializecomponant routine ... which would be a bad idea anyway and I don't want to set the size property in every blessed form to a static value

Thanks for any assistance (VB.NET)

Comment: [Create custom project and item templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/creating-custom-project-and-item-templates?view=vs-2017). --  [CustomParameters element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/customparameters-element-visual-studio-templates?view=vs-2017).

Comment: everytime you open a form, you have to set the size, if you want to keep the size you got after resizing. or else it revert to its original size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an option to run the code in design mode of a form, you can put the code in base class of the form.

The code which you put in the base class of a form will run in design mode of the inherited form. So if you would like to run a code in design mode of a form, you can create a base form and inherit from that form. Then put your code in the methods of the base form.

**Example**

1. Add New Item and choose a `Form` and set the name to `MyBaseForm`.
2. Paste the following code in `MyBaseForm.vb`:

   ```
   Imports System.ComponentModel
   Public Class MyBaseForm
       Protected Overrides Sub OnSizeChanged(e As EventArgs)
           If DesignMode Then
               Dim s = New Size(My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width * 0.75,
                                My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Height * 0.75)
               TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(Me)("Size").SetValue(Me, s)
           End If
           MyBase.OnSizeChanged(e)
       End Sub
   End Class
   ```
3. Build the project.
4. Add New Item and choose a `InheritedForm` and choose `MyBaseForm` as the base form.

Comment: Excellent .. I stumbled on a similar solution of creating an invisible custom control that set the size of its parent when the parent changed. so dropping it on a form set the form's size, but your solution is closer to what I wanted,, thanks!

Comment: The requirement is a bit strange to me but I assume changing the size at design time is not an xy problem. Anyway, at least now you know one of the solutions for *How to execute code in design mode for WinForms.*